# How to write an rspec for raise, rescue block

Tags: ruby, rspec

I want to write rspec to test this method

```
def path_exception
  begin
    # @path value need to mocked/stubbed if needed.
    raise if Dir[File.join(@path, '**/*.rb')].empty?
  rescue 
    puts 'Not appropriate path found'
  end
end
```

I have written this rspec and calling only the method but its still giving success without any expectation

```
context '#wrong_path_exception' do
  it 'raises exception when path is not valid' do
    operation.path_exception
  end
end
```

what is the correct way to write rspec for raise if condition true/false and rescue.

Comment: If I understand the code correctly, the method doesn't raise an exception – it rescues the raised exception itself and prints a message instead. In that case, you can use RSpec's [`output` matcher](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-10/docs/built-in-matchers/output-matcher).

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't use exceptions for control flow. Just use your `if` expression without `raise` and `rescue`.

Comment: if i only calls the method in rspec  operation.path_exception it gets success. Without expect it gets success why?

Comment: _"Without expect it gets success why?"_ – that's the way RSpec works. Examples without expectations currently don't fail. See GitHub issue [#759](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/759) and the (now closed) [#404](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/404) for insights.

Comment: `allow($stdout).to receive(:write)      #avoid puts on console
      operation.wrong_path_exception
      expect {puts}.to output.to_stdout`          #expecting a puts block

Comment: am i correct please let me know. getting success  @stefan

Answer (score 1):

Although your method calls `raise`, that exception isn't visible to the outside because of `rescue`, which turns it into output to stdout.

You could set an expectation via the [`output` matcher](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-10/docs/built-in-matchers/output-matcher), e.g.:

```
expect { operation.path_exception }.to output('Not appropriate path found').to_stdout
```

Note that you don't need exceptions to generate output. You can just use [control expressions](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html) like your `if` expression:

```
def path_exception
  if Dir[File.join(@path, '**/*.rb')].empty?
    puts 'Not appropriate path found'
  end
end
```

But according to the method's name (`path_exception`) I think you actually want to raise an exception. So the actual fix might be to remove `rescue`:

```
def path_exception
  if Dir[File.join(@path, '**/*.rb')].empty?
    raise 'Not appropriate path found'
  end
end
```

along with the [`raise_error` matcher](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-10/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher):

```
expect { operation.path_exception }.to raise_error('Not appropriate path found')
```